# How to avoid removing of all childs while deleting the first child of the list?

Tags: jquery, html

HTML:

```
<ul id="ll">
    <li class="ba">Blah1<a id="nex" href="#">Run Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#ll li').append('<li class="ba" id="new">Blah2<a id="dll" href="#">del</a></li><li class="ba">Blah3<a id="dll" href="#">del</a></li><li class="bba">Blah4<a id="dll" href="#">del</a></li><li class="bba">Blah5<a id="dll" href="#">del</a></li>');

    $('#nex').click(function() {
        var ne = $('#nex').next().html();
        console.log(ne);
        $('#ll:first-Child').empty().append(ne);

        //$('#ll:first-Child').empty().replaceWith(ne);
    });
});


$(document).on('click', '#dll', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

In this code i want to add childs into the lists dynamically, and then after adding the elements i want to replace the first child with the nextchild whatever currently it is , doing that by replacing all childs are deleted , only the second child has been replace with the first child.And then I also want to delete the current child of the list by clicking del link.

http://jsfiddle.net/V6g8d/26/

Comment: How does the code you have right now not work?

Comment: You basically want to remove the first one, not replacing the first with the second one.

You are appending it wrongly, as you are inserting the "<li>" into the previous "<li>"

Comment: You are adding the child in wrong node. $('#ll li').append()..  Change this to $('#ll').append

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have duplicate `id` attributes on the page, and use them as selectors. Did you mean to use classes instead?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#ll')
    .append('<li class="ba">Blah2<a href="#">del</a></li><li class="ba">Blah3<a href="#">del</a></li><li class="ba">Blah4<a href="#">del</a></li><li class="ba">Blah5<a href="#">del</a></li>')
    .on('click', 'li a', function() {
      $(this).parent().remove();
    });

  $('#nex').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().clone().appendTo('#ll').children('a').text('del');
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ll">
  <li class="ba">Blah1<a id="nex" href="#">Run Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a jsfiddle working

```
<ul id="ll">
    <li class="ba">Blah1<a id="nex" href="#">Run Test</a></li>
</ul>


$(document).ready(function(){

$('#ll').append('<li class="ba" id="new">Blah2<a class="dll" href="#">del</a></li><li class="ba">Blah3<a class="dll" href="#">del</a></li><li class="bba">Blah4<a class="dll" href="#">del</a></li><li class="bba">Blah5<a class="dll" href="#">del</a></li>');

$('#nex').click(function(){
    var $nex = $(this);
    $nex.closest("li.ba").remove();
});

$(document).on('click','.dll',function(){
      $(this).closest("li").remove();
  });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/at515Lpy/

Basically you have a ton of errors:

- You are adding li inside another li
- You are using duplicate #ids, so I changed them to "dll" class.
- It's not very clear what "Run test" should do, basically, I remove
  the first div.

What do you need "Run Test" to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi now i thing you want to this .

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#ll > li').after('<li class="ba" class="new">Blah2<a class="dll" href="#">del</a></li><li class="ba">Blah3<a class="dll" href="#">del</a></li><li class="bba">Blah4<a class="dll" href="#">del</a></li><li class="bba">Blah5<a class="dll" href="#">del</a></li>');
    
    $('.dll').on('click', function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    
});
```

```css
#nex{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ll">
    <li class="ba">Blah1<a id="nex" href="#">Run Test</a></li>

</ul>
```

used on id in one single page if your used to multiple than used to class i m using class in this example check it .